# Advice needed with items in a customised list view

Tags: android

I was working on an android project, the project includes an activity which has a edit text field, the edit text field when filled by the user should be entered in the customised list view along with the date the entry was made,
I can't decide as how should I create a new object for each edit text field and how should I display the date for each edit field?,could somebody please help me with this, I'd really appreciate the effort.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a ListActivity. You would be able to display only the text previously entered, with or without the date :)
You can have more information in the documentation : [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)
And in the ressources tutorial : [Hello ListView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)

Do not hesitate to post a bit of code : it would be easier to help :)